# IE8 - Footer div floating in the middle

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-float, footer

I already tried out a lot of suggestions that were made in related threads on Stackoverflow. However it doesn't seem to have worked. Please check  my site http://popundernetwork.com - the footer works correctly on Chrome, Firefox,etc. But on IE 8, the footer not only floats right in the middle, but also prevents people from entering details on the form input screen.

I have already tried the position:absolute; bottom:0; commands as well as clear:both on the footer div. This has still not fixed the issue on the IE 8 browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by footer is floating in the middle. It seems to work properly in IE 8. I'm using IE 9. I tried it with IE 8 document mode. can you elaborate little more.

Comment: use postion:relative so that it does not go off the DOM structure. This is why your div is floating around. This is evident in all browsers in your site if you minimize the browser size. Also position the relative div to bottom and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks dinukadev, that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Just so future visitors know, you hold NEVER, EVER use or create a service like the URL above.

Answer (score 0):

It's issue is not *fixed* in any browser if you ask me. (no pun intended)

Your body is becoming shorter than page height when you make you footer absolute.
Remove the position and the padding entirely from your footer and it should solve everything.